# What is the structural formula of a monomer of hydroxypropyl methylcellulose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, polymers

I'm studying the properties of the polymer [hydroxypropyl methylcellulose (HPMC)](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Hydroxy-propyl-methyl-cellulose) with the static scattering technique. I'm trying to interpret the molar mass obtained with a Zimm plot, that is $\pu{(3.08\pm 0.47)\times 10^{6} g mol^-1}.$

In particular, I would like to calculate the number of unites in a polymer chain, but I don't understand from the PubChem reference  what is the formula of single monomer. At the website above, I've found the formula $\ce{C56H108O30},$ but at the same site there is a molecular structure with a lesser number of carbons (about 30).

What is the formula for a HPMC monomer?

Comment: It's not a *natural* polymer and I wonder how could you *not* guess the unit from the name of the substance.

Comment: Yes it' s true! Should I start from a single glucose molecule adding the hydroxypropylic and  methilic groups?

Comment: Indeed from the name as it is there is formally no way to draw the monomer. This is because the reference is given to the polymer. We only know that a polymer called cellulose has some hydroxypropyl and methyl groups here and there. One working on it will certainly know, but strictly formally one can't.

Comment: Just to say that I am not surprised by the question. Nothing more, as this is quite normal in cellulose derivatives at least.